# Add break-line between files Grunt - concat

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I would like to know if there is a way to add a line between each file when we concat the files using Grunt concat.

Because I get errors due to some inline comments in end of file which, when they are merged comments also the first line of the next file.

A little tricky actually, I'm removing these comments manually but if I could avoid definitively this issue, could be better.

Just add a line for each file concat could be great.
I'll remove comments and spaces with Grunt - uglify next.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat mentions the `separator` option and even gives a usage example for using a custom separator.

Here's their example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['src/intro.js', 'src/project.js', 'src/outro.js'],
      dest: 'dist/built.js',
    },
  },
});
```

If that doesn't do it for you, you can probably change the `seapartor` line to:

```
separator: grunt.util.linefeed + ';' + grunt.util.linefeed;
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll use '\n' instead of ';'. I don't think the ';' is useful. Or maybe both... To avoid non-end instruction when minifying the file! So ';\n' should be better!

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) documentation, you could try the `separator` option.

> Concatenated files will be joined on this string. If you're
>   post-processing concatenated JavaScript files with a minifier, you may
>   need to use a semicolon ';' as the separator.